# Transferring data from WalkMe to Heap via webhooks

Tags: webhooks, heap-analytics

I have a problem in webhooks to transfer data from walkme to heap analytics.
I added "Analytics Properties" to walkme "Name" and "Type" in the settings and I would like to transfer this information to heap.
In the webhook, I have the 3 mandatory event properties : "identity", "app_id" and "event" and when I click on "test" it works.
Now how can I pass my two additional properties.
I have the impression that we are obliged to use the property "properties" but how to put my variable "Name" and "Type" in it.

I tried to add the Event Properties : "wm.userVars.name" and "wm.userVars.type" but the test does not work.
I managed to add a new Event Properties "properties" with a fixed data, and the test works.
But I don't know how to add the dynamic data of my "Analytics Properties" in Event Properties "properties".

If anyone knows the answer, I would be really interested.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Please see discussion and solution in our online [Heap Community](https://community.heap.io/connectors-and-integrations-6/transferring-data-from-walkme-to-heap-via-webhooks-446?postid=1141#post1141)